# How can I change the input received by clicking in a datalist?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a datalist that shows the autocompletion of some fields how can I make sure that the input is only a part of that selected field??

Comment: do you need your values to be only from a set of options? Then select is a better option, datalist allows user to choose from suggestions but also to input custom text. Or what do you mean by `make input only a part of the selected field`

Comment: I use the datalist to create a suggestion of streets I need to show all the details to select the right street,  but I only need the name in the field when the user clicks

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by defining a **variable** of type number.
After selecting from the input, add a number to the variable and using `ngIf` in html or `if` in ts, Control the number of choices.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have Street Names in the dropdown and that object also includes street information as well (maybe in some other variable). So you want user to search using the street information as well but in the dropdown you just want to show the user Street names? if that's the case,
you can do something like this:

```
    <datalist>
    <option>
    {{streetName}} <span style="display:none">{{streetInfo}}</span>
    </option>
   </datalist>
```

This way your street information wont be shown but will filter the result on basis of stretInfo as well.
hope it helps.